# How to conditionally separate a cell value and add to a column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example

**testing.csv:**

```
First Name    Last Name  Profile URL
Ashleigh      Phelps     https://www.linkedin.com/in/ashleighephelps
Jonathan                 https://www.linkedin.com/in/jonathantsegal
Camilla Innes            https://www.linkedin.com/in/camilla-innes-61213628  
Rachel                   https://www.linkedin.com/in/rachel-hudesman-335b8120
Michael                  https://www.linkedin.com/in/mikeitalia
Antonio                  https://www.linkedin.com/in/antoniomolinelli
Lauren        Zsigray    https://www.linkedin.com/in/lauren-zsigray-13b5aa25
```

The code I have used will only separate which has a hyphen but how to get the last name which is with the first name?

```
df = pd.read_csv("testing.csv", sep=',', encoding="utf-8")
df = df[df['Last Name'].isnull()]
p = df.pop('Profile URL')
tmp_df = p.str.split('/')
df['Last Name'] = tmp_df.str[-1]
tmp1_df = df.pop('Last Name').str.split('-')
df['Last Name'] = tmp1_df.str[1:-1].str.join(sep='-')
df = pd.concat([df, p], axis=1)
print (df)
```

Which gives this output:

```
First Name  Last Name       Profile URL
Ashleigh    Phelps          https://www.linkedin.com/in/ashleighephelps
Jonathan                    https://www.linkedin.com/in/jonathantsegal
Camilla     Innes           https://www.linkedin.com/in/camilla-innes-61213628
Rachel      hudesman        https://www.linkedin.com/in/rachel-hudesman-335b8120
Michael                     https://www.linkedin.com/in/mikeitalia
Antonio                     https://www.linkedin.com/in/antoniomolinelli
Lauren      Zsigray         https://www.linkedin.com/in/lauren-zsigray-13b5aa25
```

**Expected output:**

```
First Name  Last Name       Profile URL
Ashleigh    Phelps          https://www.linkedin.com/in/ashleighephelps
Jonathan    tsegal          https://www.linkedin.com/in/jonathantsegal
Camilla     Innes           https://www.linkedin.com/in/camilla-innes-13628
Rachel      hudesman        https://www.linkedin.com/in/rachel-hudesman-33
Michael                     https://www.linkedin.com/in/mikeitalia
Antonio     molinelli       https://www.linkedin.com/in/antoniomolinelli
Lauren      Zsigray         https://www.linkedin.com/in/lauren-zsigray-13b5a
```

What should be used to get the output in this format

Comment: More than separate a cell value, what you need is to know where the first name ends and the surname starts... so unless you have a list of possible first names (which would be huge but possible if you consider the main ones) I don't see this as just a cell separation issue... let's see if somebody finds a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("testing.csv", sep=',', encoding="utf-8")

df.fillna('', inplace=True)

def clear_data(x):
    fname = x['First Name']
    lname = x['Last Name'].strip()
    url = x['Profile URL']
    if not lname:
        fname = fname.split(' ')[0]
        url_name = url.split('/')[-1].split('-')
        if len(url_name) > 1:
            lname = url_name[-2].title()
        else:
            index_of_fname = url_name[0].lower().find(fname.lower())
            if index_of_fname != -1:
                index_of_fname += len(fname)
                lname = url_name[0][index_of_fname:].title()

        x['First Name'] = fname
        x['Last Name'] = lname
    else:
        lname = lname.split('-')[0].strip()
        x['Last Name'] = lname

    return x


df.apply(clear_data, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Comment: this dose well only to this code not with the data in csv file

Comment: can you give your mail id so that i can send you the file

Comment: I HAVE PASTED AS testing.csv

Comment: so... give me a link :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165812/discussion-between-biniow-and-vipul-rao).

Answer (score 1):

Well this big lines do the job:

```
df.loc[(df['Last Name']=='')&(df['First Name'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split()))>1), 'Last Name'] = df.loc[df['First Name'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split()))>1, 'First Name'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[1])

df.loc[(df['First Name'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split()))>1), 'First Name'] = df.loc[df['First Name'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split()))>1, 'First Name'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0])

df.loc[(df['Last Name']=='')&(df['Profile URL'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split('-')))>1), 'Last Name'] = df.loc[df['Profile URL'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split('-')))>1, 'Profile URL'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[1])

df.loc[(df['Last Name']=='')&(df.apply(lambda x: x['First Name'].lower() in x['Profile URL'], axis=1)), 'Last Name'] = df.loc[(df['Last Name']=='')&(df.apply(lambda x: x['First Name'].lower() in x['Profile URL'], axis=1))].apply(lambda x: x['Profile URL'].split('/')[-1].replace(x['First Name'].lower(), ''), axis=1)
```

Comment: idk this gives an error like `raise ValueError('Must have equal len keys and value '
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`

Comment: I thought that your data was representative and this code works for the data you provided. Only thing you could change is `(df['Last Name']=='')` into `(df['Last Name'].isnull())` as I created the df using string data you provided.

Comment: i can mail the data it not confidential